# Jmeter Send wildcard % in JSON Payload of HTTP Request not returning correct response

Tags: json, rest, jmeter

I have a http POST request with JSON payload to search for devices owned by a customer with this body data:

```
{
  "@rpc": "1.0",
  "@data": [
    "dev%25",
    [
      "CompanyXYZ"
    ]
  ]
}
```

It should return a list of devices that begin with 'dev' like this:

```
device1
device2
device3
```

But instead is returning nothing.  My header has:

- Content-Type = application/json
- X-CLIENTID = sdfsd8

How can I search for a set of data using a wildcard character like % in the body data of my HTTP Request?  It seems like that is what I am seeing the endpoint do in our webapp.

I have tried these things with no luck:

1. adding a charset=utf-8 to the header
2. added content encoding=utf-8 to the HTTP Request and to the HTTP
   Request Defaults

I even tried the endpoint with just "dev%" and not "dev%25" but it is not encoding the % correctly and throws:

```
jmeter.protocol.http.visualizers.RequestViewHTTP: Error decoding query, maybe your request parameters should be encoded:

{
  "@rpc": "1.0",
  "@data": [
    "dev%",
    [
      "CompanyXYZ"
    ]
  ]
} java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "","
    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems using JMeter 3.1

[image: JMeter 3.1 REST JSON POST]

JSON request is set in Body Data tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image: HTTP Rest request JMEter body data]

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) for comprehensive information on various aspects of API testing with JMeter

Comment: Yes this all looks correct and does not error in jmeter.  The problem is that it actually is not returning the results.  I do the same action in the web app and I am getting several devices returned.  If I do this in jmeter no search results are returned.